# Statuscode guidelines when acting as a middle-man

Tags: http, http-status-codes, middleman, design-guidelines

Hello i want to understand if i as a server am  acting  as  a middleman between the client and another server , what should i return to the client when any of the requests from me to the other server fails?

Currently i am sending the client a generic `500` with a message containing the original message of the other server:

Other server message:  `401: Something` 
My server message: `500: Other server: 401 Something`

Is it ok , or how should the middleman behave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709834/http-status-424-or-500-for-error-on-external-dependency) on the subject

> 5xx codes are for telling the client that even though the request was fine, the server has had some kind of problem fulfilling the request.

Every other 5xx than 500 does not fit your situation => You're doing right :)