# REST API: Wrong schema vs wrong data

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Let's suppose we have a REST API that accept the following body for a create-user request:

```
{
  "username": "joe",
  "email" : "joe@domain.com"
  ...
}
```

Now I'm a bit confused and don't know when to use HTTP status 400 and when to use HTTP status 422.

When the schema is wrong (e.g. `usernamexx` instead of `username`) is it correct to return 400?

when the schema is correct but the data isn't (e.g. invalid email format like `@dummy`) is it correct to return 422?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to post a comment on this post, so am writing a short response instead.

> When the schema is wrong (e.g. usernamexx instead of username) is it correct to return 400?

A **422** response is the correct to return in this case as the syntax is incorrect. This is described in further in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133923/400-vs-422-response-to-post-of-data).

> When the schema is correct but the data isn't (e.g. invalid email format like @dummy) is it correct to return 422?

A **400** should be returned in the case of a malformed/incorrect entity. This is further described in the post mentioned above. You could further improve the response message by including a body to further explain the error.