# Error handler using $resource of Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I handle errors of the $resource angularjs?

The 422 error is returned, you can check in the second image

I'll put here two images, the first is the request, the second is the error on the console after the request. I can not find solution for this. I've looked on google and nothing.

Request:

http://gyazo.com/e1f123a957b9577bd8946d36762f44db

Console error:

http://gyazo.com/f2c0b086c58b96f89bb5019b82e1176c

My restservice.js code

```
app.factory('RestService', function($resource, $http) {
    return {
        customers: $resource(_CONFIG_REST + 'customers/:id'),
        users: $resource(_CONFIG_REST + 'users/:id')
    }
});
```

My create.js

```
app.controller('customers.create', function($scope, $state, toastr, RestService) {
    $scope.submit = function() {
        RestService.customers.save($scope.data, function(response) {
            toastr.success('The customer was added successfully');
        }, function() {
            toastr.error('An error has ocurred');
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: You need to add your code.

Comment: You are getting `HTTP Status: 422` as error code might [400 vs 422 response to POST of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133923/400-vs-422-response-to-post-of-data) help you

Comment: Yes I Know ... it's correctly

Comment: Hey Satpal, add the response, I will give the points for you, U was right :-P You gave me the solution.

Comment: I have just guide nothing more that, I have nothing to add. Glad you got the solution.

Comment: I need to close the issue :-P

Comment: I marked it duplicate, accept it

Comment: Thanks my friend :)