# Why does Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes not include 422 Unprocessable Entity?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes` contains lots of status code constants useful for returning from a controller and can for example be used like this in a controller:

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
```

But oddly the `StatusCodes` class contains no value for 422 Unprocessable Entity, at least not in Asp.Net Core 1.0.1.  Why doesn't it contain `StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity` ?

Has this http status code been depreciated by some spec I am unaware of?  Or is there some other reason that 422 Unprocessable Entity wasn't included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it is included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes`.

Please find current list in: [StatusCodes.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/StatusCodes.cs)

HTTP Status Code 422 is WebDAV specific (RFC 4918) and it was added to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes` a little bit later.

*(See details of [Added HTTP Status codes #654](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/654) pull request)*

But it was a few months ago, so the question is what version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

**Update:**

As Ron C noticed - this status code is included in v1.1 (and not available in v1.0.1).

Comment: Sure enough!  Thank you.  I'm running Asp.Net Core 1.0.1 and it doesn't exist in this version.  But I see that it does exist in 1.1 on GitHub thanks to the info you provided.

Comment: Yes, I'm running v1.1 so I see const for 442, but you are right, it looks like it was included after v1.0.1 was released.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t know why but I did a quick search and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133923/400-vs-422-response-to-post-of-data).

As of 2015, @Tom Christie mentioned the following:

> Behaviorally both 400 and 422 response codes will be treated the same
> by clients and intermediaries, so it actually doesn't make a concrete
> difference which you use.

And this:

> 422 Is specifically a WebDAV extension, and is not referenced in RFC
> 2616 or in the newer [HTTPbis specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26#section-6.5.1).

Maybe...just maybe...the reason why the status code 422 isn’t part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes` might be because it is a WebDAV extension but don’t take my word for it as I’m only trying to raise awareness as to what could be the cause.