# REST API - Should I return an error if request body has more information than needed?

Tags: web-services, rest

My current configuration limits the number of properties and size of the request body for every endpoint. Should I return an error if request body has more information than needed?

Let's say that `/authenticate` endpoint requires JSON body shown below:

```
{
  "login": "string";
  "password": "string";
}
```

and the user sends a request

```
{
  "login": "mylogin",
  "password": "mypassword",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Should REST API return an error in this case?

Comment: sending `Bad Request (400)` looks more sensible.

Comment: as someone said earlier, why not just ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options here:

**1. Ignoring fields that don't affect request processing and cannot change it.**

By default, most of JSON/XML parsers, filling an entity, skip fields that haven't been reflected in the model.

**2. Strict field matching and returning the HTTP `422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY` or `400 BAD REQUEST` code.**

You could have a list of all allowed fields for each endpoint to compare an incoming request with.

It depends on your API design and the style you want users to follow.

Comment: 400 maybe. 422 is defined by RFC 4918 - WebDav and should be use only if WebDav capabilities are supported. But honestly i don't know. there is mixed opinions about this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133923/400-vs-422-response-to-post-of-data.

Comment: I've never regretted choosing #2 over #1.  Strict field matching may feel like it restricts consumers, but often it can mitigate later frustration.

Consider a consumer calling an API with optional properties in the model. If the API consumer has a typo in the name of an optional property, the API will respond with a 200, and the consumer will take considerably more time debugging than if a 400 were returned. Often the most frustrating bugs arise out of innocent typos like "laed" instead of "lead".

Answer (score 0):

By default, the request is not validated for additional fields. For json schema there's a parameter '*additionalProperties*', whose value can be set to false.

Refer this link [Understanding JSON schema validation](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html). Relevant portion copied below.

> The additionalProperties keyword is used to control the handling of extra stuff, that is, properties whose names are not listed in the properties keyword. By default any additional properties are allowed.
>   The additionalProperties keyword may be either a boolean or an object. If additionalProperties is a boolean and set to false, no additional properties will be allowed.