# Is invalid form data submission an "Error" or "OK" in terms of return HTTP status code?

Tags: validation, http-status-codes

My specific use case is a rails app, but I'm not sure this matters much.

This question is not so much "advice" but wondering if there is industry consensus on what type of HTTP status code to return when form submission data is not valid.

For my jquery ajax calls, having invalid submissions return "OK" would require:

```js
    $.ajax(
    )
    .done( (data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        //was invalid
      } else {
        //was good
      }
    })
    .fail( (jqXHR) => {
      //this not called unless exception
    })
```

But returning something like 422 Unprocessable Entity would allow:

```js
    $.ajax(
    )
    .done( (data) => {
      //was good
    })
    .fail( (jqXHR) => {
      //do this for invalid data
    })
```

Just wanting to be on the right side of history, lol.

Answer (score -1):

Mentionning

> form submission data is not valid

will result in a `4xx` as it's a client error. `422` would mean data is sent as a JSON but the given JSON is malformed (the stored data is correct). It might be for instance a missing coma, a missing bracket. In many cases `400` is way more appropriate, you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20215807/11825162) which details differences between `400`, `422` *(and `415`)*.

Comment: Respectfully, you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Invalid form data submission should result in a 4xx as answered. This does answer the (only) question asked here, otherwise please detail your post

Comment: It will only result in a 4xx if I make it result that way. The question is should I and why. This does somewhat misunderstand the question. It's not about an invalid request in terms of structure of the request, but about the validity of the well-formed data. The data could be invalid because the end date is before the start date for example, or because the the phone number is too long. Anyway, I think it's reasonable for invalid data (not an invalid request) to be "unprocessable 422".

Comment: My hesitation is that in the event that data submitted is found to be invalid for whatever reason, explanations will be sent back to the user. Technically the network communication with the server actually succeeded, but the intent of the request (to save the data) failed.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting this information. I'm seeing "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422