# Python is returning 422 error on request POST

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a webscraper - python Selenium in a docker container to digital ocean which I can request.POST a url to from a different website. Using the console on digital ocean I can run the code and it works fine. So I believe the issue is in how I am receiving or posting the url to the webscraper. Currently it is returning a `<Response [422]>`

Here is the code, I pass the extract_text_via_scraper_service function a url in the form of a string e.g. "https://google.com", and the docker app should return the title in the form of a dictionary:

```
SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER=os.environ.get("SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER")
SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT=os.environ.get("SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT")
def extract_text_via_scraper_service(website): # website = url
    answer = {}
    if SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT is None:
        return answer
    if SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER is None:
        return answer
    if website is None:
        return answer

    # send url through HTTP POST
    # return dict {}
    headers={
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {SCRAPER_API_TOKEN_HEADER}"
    }

    r = requests.post(SCRAPER_API_ENDPOINT, data=website, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    if r.status_code in range(200, 299):
        if r.headers.get("content-type") == 'application/json':
            answer = r.json()

   return answer
```

docker file:

```
import pathlib
import os
import io
from functools import lru_cache
from fastapi import (
    FastAPI,
    Header,
    HTTPException,
    Depends,
    Request,
    )
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_auth_token: str
    debug: bool = False
    echo_active: bool = False
    app_auth_token_prod: str = None
    skip_auth: bool = False

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"

@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    return Settings()

settings = get_settings()

DEBUG=settings.debug

BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
UPLOAD_DIR = BASE_DIR / "uploads"


app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(BASE_DIR / "templates"))
# REST API

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse) # http GET -> JSON
def home_view(request: Request, settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "abc": 123})

def verify_auth(authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    if settings.debug and settings.skip_auth:
        return
    if authorization is None:
        raise HTTPException(detail="Invalid endpoint", status_code=401)
    label, token = authorization.split()
    if token != settings.app_auth_token:
        raise HTTPException(detail="Invalid endpoint", status_code=401)

@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(website, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    verify_auth(authorization, settings)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(website)

    
    title = "Sorry, we failed to get the correct name"
    

    #title
    try:
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//title")
        title = title.get_attribute("innerText")
    except:
        pass
    
    print(title)
   
    return{"results": title, "original": title}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133923/400-vs-422-response-to-post-of-data does this help?

Comment: It confirms that it is not an issue with authorisation. So I suspect the issue relates to how I am posting / receiving the url, it seems to not understand the datatype, but I just tried changing the docker parameter to website:str and it still returns the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: what does `r.text` return?

Comment: r.text returns `{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}`. I am thinking I need to encode the url somehow first.

Comment: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3373 there we go :)

Comment: @grumpyp - I have updated the receiving docker file to say `website: str` and the `request.POST` is now using `json={'website': website}`but now I am now getting the following from `print(r.text)` `{"detail":[{"loc":["query","website"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}` and from `print(r.json)`
`<bound method Response.json of <Response [422]>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was here

old:

```
@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(website, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    verify_auth(authorization, settings)
```

new:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    website: str

@app.post("/") # http POST
async def prediction_view(requested_url: Item, authorization = Header(None), settings:Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
```

Ensure you are passing the data being posted as JSON. Relevant FastApi documentation can be found [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#request-body-path-query-parameters), note the following:
The function parameters will be recognized as follows:

- If the parameter is also declared in the path, it will be used as a
  path parameter.
- If the parameter is of a singular type (like int,    float, str,
  bool, etc) it will be interpreted as a query parameter.
- If the parameter is declared to be of the type of a Pydantic model,
  it will be interpreted as a request body.