# HTTP GET Request Params - which error code? 400 vs 404 vs 422

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, http-error

I've read a lot of questions about `400` vs `422`, but they are almost for HTTP `POST` requests for example this one: [400 vs 422 response to POST of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363900/2230325).

I am still not sure what should I use for `GET` when the required parameters are sent with wrong values.
Imagine this scenario:

- I have the endpoint `/searchDeclaration`, with the parameter `type`.
- My declarations have 2 types: **TypeA** and **TypeB**.

So, I can call this endpoint like this: `/searchDeclaration?type=TypeA` to get all **TypeA** declarations.

What error should I send when someone calls the endpoint with an invalid `type`? For example: `/searchDeclaration?type=Type123`

Should I send `400`? I am not sure it is the best code, because the parameter is right, only the value is not valid.

The `422` code looks like it is more suitable for `POST` request.

**EDIT:**
After some responses I have another doubt.
The `/searchDeclaration` endpoints will return the declaration for the authenticated user. **TypeA** and **TypeB** are valid values, but some users don't have submitted a **TypeB** declaration, so when they call `/searchDeclaration?type=TypeB` which error should I send? Returning `404` does not seem right because the URI is correct, but that user does not have a declaration for that value yet. Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URI is wrong, use [404 Not Found](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.5).

> The *404 (Not Found)* status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

The [target resource](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-7.1) is, as one might expect, identified by the target URI.

Aside from the semantics of the response, 404 indicates that the response is cacheable - meaning that general purpose caches will know that they can re-use this response to future requests

---

> I am not sure it is the best code, because the parameter is right, only the value is not valid.

The fact that *this* URI includes parameters and values is an implementation detail; something that we don't care about at the HTTP level.

Casually: 404 means "the URI is spelled wrong"; but doesn't try to discriminate which part(s) of the URI have errors.  That information is something that you can include in the body of the response, as part of the [explanation of the error situation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5).

---

> Am I overthinking this?

No, but I don't think you are thinking about the right things, [yet](https://xkcd.com/1053/).

One of the reasons that you are finding this challenging is that you have multiple *logical* resources sharing the same target URI.  If each user declaration document had its own unique identifier, then the exercise of choosing the right response semantics would be a lot more straight forward.

Another way of handing it would be to *redirect* the client to the more specific URI, and then handle the response semantics there in the straight forward way.

It's trying to use a common URI for different logical resources AND respond without requiring an extra round trip that is making it hard.  Bad news: this is one of the trade offs that ought to have been considered when designing your resource identifiers; if you don't want this to require harder thinking, don't use this kind of design.

The good news: 404 is still going to be fine - you are dealing with authorized requests, and the rules about sharing responses to authorized requests mean that the only possible confusion will be if different users are sharing the same private cache.

---

Remember: part of the point is that all resources share a common, general purpose message vocabulary.  Everything is supposed to look like a document being served by a boring web server.

The fact that there's a bunch of complexity of meaning behind the resource is an implementation detail that is correctly hidden behind the uniform interface.

Comment: Thanks I understand your response, but I have another question. I edited the post and added another example where the **TypeB** is valid but some users don't have a value for that type. Which error should I send? 404 does not seem right because the URI is correct, but that user does not have a declaration for that value yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, it all depends on your '`type`' variable.

1. If '`type`' is an `ENUM`, which only allows '`typeA`' and '`typeB`', and your client sends '`type123`', the service will respond with a '`400 Bad Request`' `error`, you don't need to check. In my opinion, this should be ideal, since if you need to add new '`type's` in the future, you will only have to add them in the `ENUM`, instead of doing 'if-else' inside your code to check them all.
2. In case the 'type' variable is a `String`, the controller will admit a '`type123`' and you should be the one to return an error, since the client request is not malformed, but rather it is trying to access a resource that does not exist.

In this case, you can return a `404 Not Found error`, (that resource the client is filtering by cannot be found), or a `422` `error` as you say, since the server understands the request, but is not able to process it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for a moment that the resource you are querying is returning a set of entries that do contain certain properties. If you don't specify a filter you will basically get a (pageable) representation of those entries either as embedded objects or as links to those resources.

Now you want to filter the results based on some properties these entries have. Most programming languages nowadays provide some lambda functionality in the form of

```
List filteredList = list.filter(item => item.propertyX == ...)...;
```

The result of such a filter function is usually a list of items that fulfilled the specified conditions. If no items met the given condition then the result will be an empty list.

Applying certain filter conditions on the Web can be designed similarly. Is it really an error when a provided filter expression doesn't yield any entries? IMO it is not an error in terms of the actual message transport itself as the server was able to receive and parse the request without any issues. As such it has to be some kind of business rule that states that only admissible values are allowed as input.

If you or your company consider the case of a provided filter value for a property returning no results as an error or you perform some i.e. XML or JSON schemata validation on the received payload (for complex requests) then we should look at how those mentioned HTTP errors are defined:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). (Source: [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1))

Here, it is clearly the case that you don't want to process requests that come with an invalid property value and as such decline the request as such.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions. ([Source: RFC 4918 (WebDAV)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4918#section-11.2))

In this case you basically say that the payload was actually syntactically correct but failed on a semmantical level.

Note that `422 Unprocessable Entity` stems from WebDAV while `400 Bad Request` is defined in the HTTP specification. This can have some impact if your API serves arbitrary HTTP clients. Ones that only know and support the HTTP error codes defined in the HTTP sepcification won't be able to really determine the semantics of the `422` response. They will still consider it as a user error, but won't be able to provide the client with any more help on that issue. As such, if your API needs to be as generic as possible, stick to `400 Bad Request`. If you are sure all clients support `422 Unprocessable Entity` go for that one.

#### General improvement hints

As you tagged your question with [rest](/questions/tagged/rest), let's see how we can improve this case.

REST is an architectural style with an intention of decoupling clients from servers to make the former one more failure tollerant while allowing the latter one to evolve freely over time. Servers in such architectures should therefore provide clients with all the things clients need to make valid requests. To avoid having clients to know upfront what a server expects as input, servers usually provide some kind of input mask clients can use to fill in stuff the server needs.

On the browsable Web this is usually accomplished by [HTML Forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html). The form not only teaches your client where to send the request to, which HTTP operation to use and which representation format the request should actually use (usually given implicitly as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) but also the sturcture and properties the server supports.

In HTML forms it is rather easy for the server to restrict the input choices of a client by using something along the lines of

```html
<form action="/target">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This doesn't really remove the needs to check and verify the correctness of the request on the server side, tough you make it much easier for the client to actually perform a valid request.

Unfortunately, HTML forms itself have their limits. I.e. they only allow `POST` and `GET` requests to be issues. While `encType` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, if you want to transfer files you should use `multipart/form-data`. Other than that, any valid content-type should be admissible.

If you prefer JSON-based payloads over HTML you might want to look into [JSON Forms](https://jsonforms.io/), [HAL forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [Ion Forms](https://ionspec.org/#forms) among others.

Note though that you should adhere to the [content type negotiation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.4) principles. Most often proactive content type negotiation is performed where a client sends its preferences within the `Accept` header and the server will select the best match somehow and return either the resource mapped to that representation format or respond with a `406 Not Acceptable` response. While the standard doesn't prevent returning a default representation in such caes, it bears the danger that clients won't be able to process such responses then. A better alternative here would be to fall back to reactive negotiation where the server responds with a `300 Muliple Choice` response where a client has to select one of the provided alternatives and then send a `GET` request to the selected alternative URIs to retrieve the content in the payload may be able to process.

If you want to provide a simple link a client can use to retrieve filtered results, the server should provide the client already with the full URI as well as a [link relation name](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) and/or [extension relation type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.2) that the client can use to lookup the URI to retrieve the content for if interested in.

Both, forms and link-relation support, fall under the HATEOAS umbrella as they help to remove the need for any external documentation such as OpenAPI or Swagger documentation.

---

To sum things up, I would rethink whether a provided property value that does not exist should really end up as a business failure. I think returning an empty list is just fine here as you clearly state that way that for the given criterias no result was obtainable. If you though still want to stick to a business error check what clients actually make use of your API. If they support `422` go for that one. If you don't know, better stick to `400` as it should be understood by all HTTP clients equally.

In oder to remove the likelihood of ending up with requests that issue invalid property values, use forms to teach clients how requests should look like. Through certain elements or properties you can already teach a client that only a limited set of choices is valid for a certain property. Instead of a form you could also provide dedicated links a client can just use to obtain the filtered result. Just make sure to issue those links with meaningful link relatin names then.